# Show default image in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, default

I'm retrieving data using a free API. I'm trying to use a default image for the objects that do not have them.

This is the structure of my project:

[image: Structure of the project]

In `movies.service.tsx` I fetch the data and assign to the property **picture** of **movie** object the value retrieved from the database (in case there is no value, `undefined` is assigned):

```
import("../images/default-poster.png");

const movieApiBaseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
const posterBaseUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300";
export interface Movie {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    rating: number;
    description: string;
    picture?: string;
    date: string;
  }

  export function fetchMovies(): Promise<Movie[]> {
   return fetch(
     `${movieApiBaseUrl}/discover/movie?sort_by=year.desc&api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
   )
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((res) => mapResult(res.results))
     .catch(() => {
         return [];
     });
 }

 // = movie has to be after const {} here
 function mapResult(res: any[]): Movie[] {
   return res.map((movie) => {
     const {
       id,
       title,
       vote_average,
       overview,
       poster_path,
       date,
     } = movie;
     return {
       id: id,
       title: title,
       rating: vote_average,
       description: overview,
       picture: poster_path ? `${posterBaseUrl}${poster_path}` : undefined,
       date: date,
     };
   });
 }
```

How could I import file `default-poster.png` to `movies.service.tsx` and assign its' path to  the picture property instead of assigning `undefined` so that I could later use it in `MovieCards.tsx`?

Comment: I was not allowed to assign `img` to `picture` property by Typescript. I have also consoled out img value and it is equal to a module

Comment: Module
default: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA <...>"
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

The solution is assigning the import '../images/no-image-available.png' to a variable and then passing that variable as the third operand of ternary operator: `picture: poster_path ?` ${posterBaseUrl}${poster_path} `: noImage`